# Bucket policy for redirecting from ALB to S3 (Webhosting)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

The following resources exist in the same VPC

- AWS-S3
- AWS-ALB

**S3**

There is one file in S3.

This is an html page and uses webhosting.

However, we don't want S3 to be public access.

**ALB**

We use ALB for Open ID Connect authentication, not balancing, use. [Simplify Login with Application Load Balancer Built-in Authentication | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/).

**ALB-S3**

I am redirecting you to the webhosting page.

**My question**

How can I make sure that I can only access the bucket policy in S3 via ALB?
At first, I thought about controlling it by the global IP of the source of the connection.
However, this is not desirable as it would allow direct access to the S3 webhosting page without going through the ALB.

Comment: ALB does not access your S3. Only the instances can do it. So you can limit bucket access to an IAM role associated with the instances only.

Comment: An alternative would be to use Amazon Cognito to perform authentication, and then use credentials from Cognito to access S3.